# Difference between entities and relations in databases

Tags: database, entity, relation

I want to know if an entity is just a table in the database modelling context? And which is the difference between an entity and a relation? I know that the relation is the base concept of relational databases and has tabular presentation. Are the entity and the relation the same thing? Note: Do not confuse the relation with the relshionship.

Comment: You have a database that includes table(s) that include(s) entitites.

Answer (score 0):

An entity is somting like an object, you can put a name to an entity.
A relation is a "link" beetwen entity, you can put a verb to an entity, in your MCD of your databases.
for exemple :

in your MCD DOG end are entity end part of is the relation

```
+-------+                +-----+
|DOG    |                |RACE |
|-------|                |-----|
|name   |---(part of)----|name |
|age    |                +-----+
+-------+
```

in your MPD this MCD become :

```
+--------+                         +---------+
|tDog    |                         |tRace    |
|--------|                         |---------|
|id_tDog |                      +--|id_tRace |
|nameDog |  +--(tRace_to_tDog)--|  |nameRace |
|ageDog  |  |                      +---------+
|FK_tRace|<-+
+--------+
```